# "PT" Formatted time string in python

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.6, iso

I'm receiving a string which is formatted in the following way: "PTXMYS" Where X is the amount of minutes and Y is the amount of seconds.

I'd like to turn that string into an `int` which presents the amount of seconds in total.
I tried using `datetime` and other stuff and it just won't work for me, I read online that this formatting is standard for iso8601 so it's weird for me that it doesn't really work.

String example:

```
x="PT4M13S"
```

Comment: the string format is [ISO 8601 duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)

Answer (score 6):

there is a third-party library that can parse these strings, [`isodate`](https://pypi.org/project/isodate/):

```
import isodate
isodate.parse_duration("PT4M13S")
# datetime.timedelta(seconds=253)
isodate.parse_duration("PT4M13S").total_seconds()
# 253.0
```

And for completeness, there is an option to do this with `datetime`'s `strptime` and `timedelta`'s `total_seconds()`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
# parse minute and second to datetime object:
t = datetime.strptime("PT4M13S","PT%MM%SS")
# convert to timedelta to get the total seconds
td = timedelta(minutes=t.minute, seconds=t.second)
td.total_seconds()
# 253
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can easily be solved using regex. Try this out:

```py
import re
m, s = re.findall('PT(\d+)M(\d+)S',x)[0]
total_secs = 60*int(m) + int(s)
print(total_secs)
```

Output:

```
253
```